# How to get the characters from a UTF-8 string?

Tags: c, character, multibyte-characters

```
char *w = "Artîsté";
printf("%lu\n", strlen(w));
int z;
for(z=0; z<strlen(w); z++){
    //printf("%c", w[z]);  //prints as expected
    printf("%i: %c\n", z, w[z]);//doesn't print anything
}
```

If I run this, it fails at the `î`. How do I print a multibyte char and how do I know when a I've hit a multibyte character?

Comment: *how do I know when a I've hit a multibyte character?* The high-order bit is a 1.

Comment: You might want to look at what UTF8 is:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: Which line does it crash on?  What platform?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "crashes"?  Surely your program doesn't experience a sudden abnormal termination.

Comment: There's nothing about the code sample that should make it crash. What's really happening?

Comment: (And it shouldn't "crash" -- it should only result in a garbage character being printed.)

Comment: sorry, it doesn't crash, just doesn't print anything. "The high-order bit is a 1" sounds like the right path. How do I check if "The high-order bit is a 1"?

Answer (score 1):

If your execution environment uses UTF-8 (Linux, for example), your code will work as-is, as long as you set a suitable locale, as in `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf9");` before calling that printf.

demo: http://ideone.com/zFUYM

Otherwise, your best bet is probably to convert to wide string and print that. If you plan on doing something other than I/O with the individual characters of that string, you will have to do it anyway.

As for hitting a multibyte char, the portable way to test is if `mblen()` returns a value greater than 1.

Comment: That code works. But it will not work with the OP `printf("%i: %c\n", z, w[z]);`

Comment: @nos Oh, it was edited after my answer. Dave's answer is correct then,

Answer (score 1):

Use the wide char and multi-byte functions:

```
int utf8len(char *str)
{
    int len, inc;

    // mblen(NULL, 0) is needed to reset internal conversion state
    for (len = 0, mblen(NULL, 0); *str; len++, str += inc)
        if ((inc = mblen(str, MB_CUR_MAX)) < 0)
            return inc;

    return len;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    char *w = "Artîsté";
    printf("%lu\n", strlen(w));

    int z, len = utf8len(w);
    wchar_t wstr[len+1];
    mbstowcs(wstr, w, len);
    for(z=0; z<len; z++)
        printf("%i: %lc\n", z, wstr[z]);
}
```

You got lucky with the first printf, because you never changed the data, once you split up the chars, your output was no longer utf8.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it stops printing output once it hits the î.

Comment: If you haven't set your locale,  put `setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");` at the top of the file.